# How modify html output

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache, regex

I need to modify html output.
I'm using afterGetOutput method in plugin for Magento \ Framework \ View \ LayoutInterface.
But the method is calling only before FPC creating. But I need to change output for every specific user.
Is there another way to solve the issue without FPC disabling ?
Thanks and sorry for my English.

module/etc/di.xml :

```
...
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface">
        <plugin name="webp_replace_tags" type="Vendor\Module\Framework\View\LayoutInterface\Plugin"/>
</type>
...
```

module/Framework/View/LayoutInterface/Plugin.php :

```
    ...

    public function afterGetOutput(LayoutInterface $layout, string $output)
    {
            $currentStore = $this->_storeManager->getStore();
            $mediaUrl = 'Placeholder';
            $re = '/(' .  addcslashes($mediaUrl, '/') . '[^\"]*).(jpg|png|jpeg|ico)/m';
            $output = preg_replace($re, '${1}.webp',$output);
        return $output;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you share some code so get idea what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes sure . I added the code.

Comment: Does your plugin called?

Comment: Yes the plugin is called but only once before FPC creation.